# Quickly switching between Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Emacs

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, python-2.x

Do people have any tips/tricks how we can quickly switch between versions in Emacs?

I find myself having to occasionally still use Python 2, while I now setup everything in Emacs to work with Python 3 (e.g. running an interactive sessions, Pylint).

Does anyone have some keybindings to quickly switch, or even have it work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

With python-mode.el delivered here:

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

run versioned Python-shells by calling

```
M-x python[VERSION] RET
```

i.e.

`M-x python3 RET` for example

When editing code or evaluating source, python-mode will read the shebang and act accordingly.

So far a short intro...

Comment: But this does not set the pylint